# c++ dynamic array of structures

Tags: c++

Could you help me organize a dynamic array of points?

I have coped with a dynamic array of integers. But I don't know
how to organize it with structures.

Here is my code so far...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>;
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int i = 0; // Array index.
  struct Point
  {
    int x;
    int y;
  };
  size_t n = sizeof(int);
  int * points = static_cast<int*>(malloc(n));
  char command;
  do
  {
    cout << "n - Create new point." << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit." << endl;
    cout << "Input a new command: ";
    cin >> command;
    if (command == 'n')
    {
      points[i] = 1;
      i++;
      /* points[i] = new Point();
         points[i].x = 1;
         points[i].y = 1; */
      // cout<<"("<<point1.x<<","<<point1.y<<")";               
    }               
    else if (command == 'q')
    {       
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        cout << points[j] <<endl;
      system("pause");
      return 0;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Please, enter a correct command." << endl << endl << endl;               
    }
  } while (true);
  system("pause");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic array in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506166/dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: [Do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845) and do not declare structs inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vectors as @iedoc suggested:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;

using namespace std;

struct SPoint
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};

int main()
{
    vector<SPoint> points;

    char command;
    do
    {
        cout << "n - Create new point." << endl;
        cout << "q - Quit." << endl;
        cout << "Input a new command: ";

        cin >> command;

        if (command == 'n')
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            cout << "X: ";
            cin >> x;

            cout << "Y: ";
            cin >> y;

            SPoint point = { x, y};
            points.push_back(point);
        }

        else if (command == 'q')
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
            {
                cout << "(" << points[i].X << "," << points[i].Y << ")";
            }

            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please, enter a correct command."<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        }
    }

    while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

look into vectors

`#include <vector>`

http://www.mochima.com/tutorials/vectors.html

Answer (score 3):

> [**`std::vector`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays.

--[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

This is what you should use in **C++**, rather than a dynamically-allocated array of `struct`s as you would in **C**.

Here is how you can start to incorporate this into your code (untested)...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef std::vector<Point> PointVector;

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    PointVector points;

    char command = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "n - Create new point." << endl;
        cout << "q - Quit." << endl;
        cout << "Input a new command: ";
        cin >> command;

        if (command == 'n')
        {
            Point new_point;
            new_point.x = 1;
            new_point.y = 1;
            points.push_back(new_point);
            cout << "(" << new_point.x << "," << new_point.y << ")\n";
        }
        else if (command == 'q')
        {
            for (PointVector::iterator it = points.begin(), end = points.end();
                it != end;
                ++it)
            {
                cout << "(" << it->x << "," << it->y << ")\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please, enter a correct command." << endl;
        }
    } while(true);
}
```

### Key points:

1. `typedef`s often make code more readable
2. [**`std::vector::push_back()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) adds to the end of the container, without you needing to keep an index or be overly-concerned about size.
3. Iterators (such as the one returned by [**`std::vector::begin()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)) make it easy to access the elements within the container, again without needing to keep an index. See also [Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)
4. This implementation would not leak `points` as your `malloc()` based implementation would do.

Comment: how do we take care of the memory management of `points` ? Doesn't it have to be deleted at the end ?

Comment: @locke14: `std::vector`'s [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) will take care of `points` when it goes out of [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). `points` *must not* be `delete`d manually.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What if `points` contains an integer array ? Will the array's memory be freed as well ?

Comment: Even then! There should be no need for you to call `delete` in modern C++! Here's some light reading for your weekend: http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/

Answer (score 2):

By the look of it, you are using `malloc` to grab enough memory to store a pointer to an int. Dont use `malloc` / `free`. This is C++, use `new` or `delete` if you really have to.

Thankfully, this is an occasion where you don't have to worry about dynamically allocating memory as you can do all this in a `vector` as follows:

```
// First create a vector of points.
std::vector<Points> points;

// Now create the Point (i'm assuming you were going to read
// it from the input stream here.)
cin >> x >> y;
Point p;
p.x = x;
p.y = y;

// And add it to the vector.
points.push_back( p );
```

It's that simple, you don't need to worry about increasing the capacity of the points vector or clearing it down at the end.